# How to link existing modman modules to magento project through modman

Tags: modman

My project contains `.modman` folder, which has more than 30 modules.

So, I installed modman and tried to link each module using

```
modman link .modman/**** --force
```

its giving a message

> "A module named '****' has already been checked out",

But nothing is actually linked.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this message because you modules are already in your `.modman` folder and `link` options tries to add it again.

Instead of `modman link PATH` you can try

```
# rebuild all modman-created symlinks (no updates performed)
modman repair
```

Or

```
# deploy an existing module
modman deploy Your_Module
# deploy all modules
modman deploy-all
```

To skip modules from being deployed, use

```
# prevent a module from deploying with deploy-all
modman skip Your_Module
```

<sup>Some more information here: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/blob/master/modman</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot  sv3n , it worked for me , but with --force , you are star :)